# Animate element on bézier path

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I want animate a div on a bézier path like on the photo below. Is this possible with javascript? Note that the two dots (white) are relative to the browser viewport (if the user pulls the screen wider, the two dots will be further from each other).

[image]

Comment: It is possible, just do [some maths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) ; ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know javascript, but I can help a little bit. Consider the following image :
[image]

In cubic-bezier timing function, `cubic-bezier(a,b,c,d)` the first two values are values `a,b` are the coordinates of the **first handle (pink)** and `c,d` are the coordinates of the **second handle (blue)**.

Now in your case, the ordinates are known. Suppose ordinates of both the handles is **1.5**, the function will be `cubic-bezier( x1, 1.5, x2, 1.5)`

For the abscissae, suppose you place **point 1** at `10vw` (viewport-width) and **point 2** at `90vw` (the `timing function end` abscissa is `100vw`), then there is no requirement for JS and you simply have to remove the **vw** and divide by `100`. The function will be `( 0.1, 1.5, 0.9, 1.5)`).

### The JS

But if its relative to viewport's left and right sides, then to find the abscissae. The following needs to be done in JS :

1. Abscissa of **1** will simply be `distance from left`.
   The abscissa of **2** will be `(Width of viewport) - Distance from right`.
2. Divide each by the width of the viewport. (in px)
3. Insert the corresponding points' abscissae in the cubic bezier function.

**EG:** 
Consider the window to be **500px** wide. Consider that **point 1** is **100px** from left and **point 2** is 100px from right. So the values inserted in the cubic bezier function will be **100/500** for **x1** and **400/500** for **x2**. The function will be `cubic-bezier(0.2, y1, 0.8, y2)`